# Proving vectors lie in the same osculating plane

Tags: differential-geometry

.

**My attempt**

If $\phi$ is the equation of the plane then 
$$\phi_{(x,y)} = p(t)+\frac{p(t+h)-p(t)}{h}r+\frac{p(t+(-h))-p(t)}{-h}s$$
If $h\rightarrow0 $ then 
$$\phi_{(x,y)} = p(t)+p'(t)r+p'(t)s$$

The resulting equation is of a line rather than a plane but the question demands a plane. Can somebody point out where have I flawed?

Is this proof okay for the question?

Comment: No, your proof does not work. The limit parametrization you get is degenerate. That is, it parametrizes a *line*, rather than a plane.

Comment: Are you saying the equation of limit plane I found is incorrect?

Comment: I'm saying the limit plane you found is not a plane.

Comment: The two derivatives $p'^+$ and $p'^-$ are the same.

Comment: Why is that? p'(t+) and p'(t-) are two different vectors. Two different vectors if not collinear always form a plane.

Comment: They are exactly the same vector. If they weren't, the parametrization $p$ wouldn't be differentiable.

Comment: Then what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, to begin with, in the sense that the parametrization $\phi_h$ describes the right plane for every $h$. Another good thing about your approach is that if we write $$\phi_h(x,y)=p(t)+xu_h+yv_h,$$ then the vectors $u_h$ and $v_h$ do not converge to $0$ as $h$ tends to $0$. The problem, however, is that both $u_h$ and $v_h$ converge to $p'(t)$, making the limit parametrization degenerate.

One way to fix this is to replace $v_h$ by a multiple of the *median* in the triangle $p(t),p(t+h),p(t-h)$. That is, let $m$ denote the midpoint of $p(t-h),p(t+h)$, and take $$v_h=\frac{m-p(t)}{h^2}.$$ This should converge to (a multiple of) the normal vector at $p(t)$ by Taylor's theorem.

**Edit:** To prove that the above $v_h$ converges to the normal vector, one needs to apply the following lemma:

*Let $f:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable at $0$. Then* $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)+f(-h)-2f(0)}{h^2}=f''(0).$$ This lemma can be proved by Tailor's theorem.

Comment: Can I not just use a more simpler vector like $$v_h=\frac{p(t+h)-p(t+h)}{h}$$

Comment: @FaiqRaees You can try... But the vector you're suggesting converges to $2p'(t)$, so it won't solve the degeneracy issue.

Comment: Can you please also show how to take limit of v_h?

Comment: @FaiqRaees Please see the edit.